# datepicker is not working for mobile version website

Tags: php, html, jquery, datepicker

`Datepicker` function is perfectly working for my website desktop version but not working for my website mobile version !!

[image: website desktop version]

[image: website mobile version]

In these two pictures you can see that in desktop version, after clicking into date field it shows a calendar but in mobile version there is no calendar showing.

**datepicker html for website desktop version**

```
<input class="form-control time_slot_searchField datepicker_class" id="datepicker" name="" type="text"  required="" placeholder="Select Date">
```

**datepicker html for website mobile version**

```
<input class="form-control col-md-4 mobile_time_slot_searchField mobile_datepicker_class" id="mobile_datepicker" name="" type="" value="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'yy/mm/dd';}" required="" style="" placeholder="Select Date">
```

**jquery for datepicker**

```
 jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#datepicker, #mobile_datepicker, #datepicker_in_clinic_detail, #modal_datepicker, #appointment_datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',minDate: 0});
  });
```

Where is the problem? Anybody help please ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
        autoclose: true, 
        todayHighlight: true
  }).datepicker('update', new Date());
});
```

```css
label{margin-left: 20px;}
#datepicker{width:180px; margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;}
#datepicker > span:hover{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<pre>
<b>Note:</b>
using <a href="getbootstrap.com/">bootstrap 3.2.0</a> and <a href="https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker">eternicode bootstrap-datepicker</a>
</pre>
<pre>
<b>@import css</b>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</pre>
<pre>
<b>@import js</b>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
</pre>
<label>Select Date: </label>
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Designerhill....your code is huge change from mine....but I want to know where is the problem?

Comment: It's using Bootstrap plugin and working fine in web and mobile. One more thing which one you used for 'datepicker' JavaScript libraries